# How to change CloudFormation template to correct Access Denied ListObjectV2 operation on s3 container

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've got a cloud formation template where I am trying to create a managed policy where I can control access to objects within a folder. I had this working at one point but I changed something in the template and need a second set of eyes to hopefully point out a typo or where I have a permission set wrong.

The CF (yaml) definition looks like:

```
 - Sid: ExternalLISTReturns
   Effect: Allow
   Action: 
     - s3:ListBucket
   Condition:
     ForAnyValue:StringEquals:
       s3:prefix: "folder1/returns/*"
   Resource: !Join
     - 's3:prefix'
     - - !Ref S3ContainerName
  - Sid: ExternalLISTUploads
    Effect: Allow
    Action: 
      - s3:ListBucket
    Condition:
      ForAnyValue:StringEquals:
        s3:prefix: "folder1/uploads/*"
    Resource: !Join
      - 's3:prefix'
      - - !Ref S3ContainerName
```

Once packaged and deployed the JSON definition looks like this in the policy manager:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": "folder1/returns/*"
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mydeployedbucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ExternalLISTReturns"
        },
        {
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": "folder1/uploads/*"
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mydeployedbucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ExternalLISTUploads"
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy looks valid but when I attempt to list items using the cli

```
aws s3 ls s3://mydeployedbucket/folder1/uploads --profile testaccount
```

I'm receiving the error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Does anything jump out as missing or needed? The intent is to only allow the listing of objects with the prefix `folder1/uploads` or `folder1/returns` for users associated to this policy

Answer (score 0):

So after digging some more I found the issue was in how I declared my resources for LIST Buckets.
I was originally defining the resource as an object not a bucket. I also found that I could just use `StringLike` in the conditional definition. `StringEquals` also worked but I did not have to explicitly declare `ForAnyValue:`
I updated the CF template so the LIST Permissions looked like this:

```
  - Sid: ExternalLISTUploads
    Effect: Allow
    Action: 
      - s3:ListBucket
    Condition:
      StringLike:  
        s3:prefix: "folder1/uploads/*"
    Resource: !Join
      - ''
      - - !Ref S3ContainerName
```